# Prevent click bubbleup without return false

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

How do i prevent a bubble up the dom when doing something like this:

```
$("*").live('mousemove',function(e){
    page.change_state();
});
```

Where we need any click handler that that element also has to execute, but we dont want this action repeating up the DOM.

We cannot use `preventDefault` or `return false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: `$('*').live('click', function(event) { ... }` to clarify

Comment: out of curiosity, why bind it to * instead of just <a>s for example?

Comment: @Matijs, i changed my code to the real code above. i want to do something whenever the user moves their mouse anywhere on the page

Comment: This sounds like a performance nightmare… are you sure you can't be more specific than that?

Comment: @Matijs, remember to tag me when you respond or i wont get it.... since then i have changed my code slightly